# Checking Perl data reference type

Tags: perl, reference

When checking reference type in Perl, why is it better to use the [constant](http://perldoc.perl.org/constant.html) pragma:

```
use constant HASH => ref {};

die "I expect a hashref" unless $ref_type eq HASH;
```

than a hardcoded string:

```
die "I expect a hashref" unless $ref_type eq 'HASH';
```

What are the advantages and disadvantages (if any)?

Comment: Why would it be better to use a module when the same functionality can be achieved with a string?

Comment: @TLP: I don't understand your comment. You seem to be reiterating the OP's question.

Comment: @TLP: yes, that's basically my question :-)

Comment: Well, the OP asks "Why is it better to use the constant pragma", and I said "Why would it be better?" Presumably he heard this somewhere in some context, which is why he asked the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The primary advantage that I can see is that, with `strict 'subs'` in effect, if an *identifier* is misspelled then it will raise an error, whereas misspelling a *string* will go unnoticed.

For instance, if I write

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data = {};

die "I expect a hashref" unless ref $data eq 'HSH';
```

then my code compiles with no problems, but will not run correctly. But if I had instead

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use constant HASH => ref {};

my $data = {};

die "I expect a hashref" unless ref $data eq HSH;
```

Then I am told

```
Bareword "HSH" not allowed while "strict subs" in use
```

before the program even starts to run.

---

This is an appropriate place to mention the `reftype` function provided by [`Scalar::Util`](https://metacpan.org/module/Scalar::Util).

The `ref` operator will return `HASH` if it is applied to a simple hash reference. However, if that reference has been *blessed* to turn it into a Perl object, `ref` will return the *name of the class* into which the reference has been blessed.

An object is most often a blessed *hash reference*, but it can be formed from a reference to any type of data -- including subroutines and typeglobs. Clearly a simple `ref` will not help us to discover what underlying Perl data type has been used to create the object, so `reftype` was written to fill this gap.

Consider this Perl program

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Scalar::Util 'reftype';

my $data = { };

print "Plain hash reference\n";
printf "  ref     => %s\n", ref $data;
printf "  reftype => %s\n", reftype $data;

bless $data, 'Class';

print "\nBlessed hash reference\n";
printf "  ref     => %s\n", ref $data;
printf "  reftype => %s\n", reftype $data;
```

**output**

```
Plain hash reference
  ref     => HASH
  reftype => HASH

Blessed hash reference
  ref     => Class
  reftype => HASH
```

As you can see, `ref` and `reftype` return the same result for a simple hash reference, whereas only `reftype` can see behind the class of a blessed reference to see that its underlying data type is unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for an extensive explanation! (You have an URL included in the code section. I am not allowed to edit it.)

Answer (score 1):

@Borodin has the correct answer in this case, typo protection.  It's worth mentioning that this technique also protects you from undocumented assumptions.  If the behavior of `ref {}` were not documented, the code would continue working if it changed later.  (I can't think of a good example where it would be useful right now).

However, the odds of the documented behavior of `ref` changing are so unlikely you should take out insurance against being hit by a dinosaur riding a meteor instead.

---

You also asked about disadvantages.  There is a very small performance hit to creating constants, but this is only at startup.  We're talking milliseconds.  Once created, they carry no penalties for being used.